# Some properties for height 1 prime ideals in the local ring

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra

Let $\mathbb{K}$ be an algebraically closed field of characteristic $0$. Let $R=\mathbb{K}[x_0,x_1,\dotsc,x_n]/I$ be the coordinate ring of an affine variety/projective variety. Also, assume that $I$ is a homogeneous prime ideal. Let $\frak{m}$ be the maximal ideal in $R$ generated by the homogeneous elements of positive degree.

I wanted to know if there are some "nice" properties satisfied by all/some height $1$ prime ideals of the local ring $R_{\frak{m}}$, say for e.g., principal.

Or,

Can we add some conditions on $R$ or $R_{\frak{m}}$ (other than UFD) so that some nice properties are satisfied by all height $1$ prime ideals or maybe, only satisfied by some height $1$ prime ideals? (obviously, if every height $1$ prime ideal is principal then $R_{\frak{m}}$ has to be a UFD)

Any help/references will be appreciated!!